# Deselect previous date in jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, date, picker

I want to validate start date and end date.For this purpose in jquery datepicker, i want to deselect or disable the previous date from the selected start date.Any body knows please help me

Answer (score 1):

So you have two datepicker instances and you want to restrict the second one to dates after the chosen startdate in the first one?

In that case you need to catch the selection event of the first instance and update the minDate option of the first instance via the setter method:

```
//setter
$('.selector').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateFromOtherDatepickerPlusOneDay);
```